# Maximum number of Http Session in Tomcat

Tags: performance, session, tomcat, garbage-collection, capacity

How many maximum numbers of active HTTP sessions (not the concurrent) tomcat 8 can handle? Tomcat 8 hosted on Linux, have only one web app containing the REST services. I have observed around 50 K active HTTP sessions during the day. I had used psi-probe to view them. The session timeout is 30 minutes. Each Http Session holds 1 MB of data. so 50 GB of session data. Heap is 450 GB, as required by the product - holds the multidimensional cube in the memory.

does this lead to any performance problems? Because I have observed frequent GCs and many Stop the Worlds ( more than 5 seconds ) 10-15 times a day.

Comment: Could you provide some metrics of the GC ? You can run jstat "attached" to your running process, or you can run jstat to read the hsperfdata file (usually found in /tmp) if there is one (default : yes).

Comment: Can not run it in production also, we don't have performance test setup